# Using XSLT to remove duplication in formatting between JavaScript and server-side C#

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, json, xslt

I have a C#.Net application that is heavily reliant on Ajax to render a page.  As the user scrolls up/down the page, new content is loaded. I deliver the raw data to Javascript via JSON and my JS then works through it to create HTML markup and write to the page.

At the same time, I need to deliver the initial page content using .Net so that the search engines and non-JS browsers have something to digest.  C# that uses the same raw data to render markup into a Literal control.

The problem is that I find myself coding the same formatting rules in both C# and JavaScript, which seems unnecessary.

A simplified example:

This in C#...

```
for (int x=0; x < lines.Length; x++)
{
    html.Append("<div>");
    html.Append(lines[x].Title);
    html.Append("</div>");
}
```

...would be matched by this in JavaScript:

```
for (int x=0; x < lines.length; x++)
{
    html += "<div>";
    html += lines[x].Title ;
    html += "</div>";
}
```

A change to the format/layout would require a change in both, which seems daft.

So my proposed solution is to use XSLT.
I'd use .Net to generate an XML file on-the-fly for the new content and both JS and .Net could then use the same XSLT file to transform to XHTML and simply output the markup.

The only downside I can see is that .Net would be generating the XML only to then convert it into markup.  This seems redundant, but then only a small percentage of the front-end markup will actually be generated by .Net, so the page load delay should be minimal.

Any thoughts on this?  Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the HTML generated server-side with C# and client-side using JavaScript is the same I'd rather get rid of the JavaScript generation, and just generate the HTML once on the server, either with an XLST or directly with the code. The JavaScript can get this HTML with an AJAX call and display it directly, attaching event handlers where needed.

Comment: How would the JavaScript 'get this HTML'?  If you mean passing the HTML through Ajax/Json, that would be quite a heavy overhead in the response to the client?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant - I added a clarification. In my experience overhaed for this kind of things is not that bad, but it depends on your HTML of course. Consider that usually a Web server will compress it.

Comment: Thanks.  Going to mark this as the answer as it has given me some food for thought, even if I'm still not sure how best to tackle this.  I'm going to do some comparison between packet size between raw data (Json) and full HTML markup and then weigh up the benefits.

Comment: Ok...let us know what you find out!

Comment: I've looked at the options and weighed each up for response size, processing required and code maintenance required.  

Given that speed of the app is the most important factor, I've decided to stick with my current solution, which is to generate HTML in .Net, but separately generate HTML from JSON in JavaScript.

This gives some maintenance (duplication) headaches, but is by far the most efficient solution as passing HTML or XML to the client is much larger than passing JSON and JS will process JSON much quicker than XML.